# Translate String to operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, logical-operators

Is there a way to translate something like the following logical operation (which uses a string due to user input)? Or will I have to check for every possibility? (> < => == =< etc.)

```
var x = 5;
var y = 3;
var operator = '>'

if (x operator y)
  doSomething();

    |
    |
    v

if (x > y)
  doSomething();
```

Comment: you can use eval(), but that'll be evil for user inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), providing you know that it is evil. Though you should definitely check if the input is valid, for example checking if it only contains the '><=' characters.

Comment: eval works perfectly for this purpose (while testing), not sure whether it is really safe or not when we go live

Comment: Is it possible to share this input with others, for example via the URL? In that case avoid it, discard this answer completely. If the user has to fill in the value himself for example in a textfield i personally dont see any problems. It is a problem when you can fool others into executing arbitrary scripts, when its just your own client it is harmless.

Comment: It will be used in an web application where users can create there own small (simple) applications for the use of data.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with an object and appropriate functions, like

```
var comparer = {
    '>': function (a, b) { return a > b; }
};
```

Use:

```
if (comparer[operator](x, y)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your way.
With `eval` you must whitelist all operators and sanitize both inputs.

Build your own interface for your needs.
May be it will `switch`:

```
switch (operator) {
  case '>': if (x > y) doSomething();
}
```

May be some more abstracted like:

```
ifArg(x).relatedWith(y).as(operator).then(doSomething);
```

May be even you'll write your own small interpreter(parser/lexer) and your users will can to write program on it.

> It will be used in an web application where users can create there own
>   small (simple) applications for the use of data. – Mathieu Brouwers

What you should not to use here is `eval`.